# grouping multiple fields using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

After doing some joins and stuff I have table in the following format

```
name    session_id   status  time
abc         1          10
xyz         2          11 
jack        2          10
zuck        1          10 
paul        1          10
```

Now I want my results to be grouped like this

```
session_id   name+status                   time
1            abc:10, zuck:10, paul:10
2            xyz:11, jack:11
```

and the result set to be sorted by time, I'm little confused how to achieve this using group by

Comment: For what database?  And what have you tried?

Comment: My db is Mysql... I'm little lost on what to try... I'm trying to do group by session_id but that won't give results in required format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your db is oracle, you can try. Afer oracle 11g r2, you can also use listagg

```
select session_id, wm_concat(name_status), time from 
(
  select session_id, (name+':'+status) as name_status, time
  from stuff
)
group by session_id
order by time
```

Comment: then use group_concat. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I need but I'm having one more problem... my sql is something like group_concat(u.firstname, \' \', u.lastname, \':\', s.punctuality_status) but this s.punctuality_status can be null in some cases... is there a way in which I can specify some default like -1 in case it is null as no result is showing up in such a case

Comment: @user401445: Use `COALESCE(status, -1)` instead of `status`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    session_id
  , GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(name, ':', COALESCE(status, -1) 
                  SEPARATOR ', '
                  ORDER BY `time`
                )  AS name_status
  , MIN(`time`)    AS min_time     --- or MAX(`time`)
FROM 
    TableX
GROUP BY
    session_id
ORDER BY
    min_time
```

You could use `time` instead of `MIN(time)`, if all rows with same `session_id` have same `time` (if `time` is functionally dependent on `session_id`). If that's not the case and you use `time`, you'll not get consistent results on that column.